# Linear Algebra Over Integer (Book Recommendation)

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, integers

I am doing research on Integer Spline. So, there are lots of system of linear diophantine equations appear, which I have to solve them within the integer. I am lacking the theory behind the system of linear diophantine equation, which is some sort of Linear Algebra Over Integer. So, is there any book out there that cover some theory about Linear Algebra Over Integer?

Comment: How about this one?  http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/ANT-F14/lec3.pdf

Comment: This is a little bit too computational. Thx

Comment: Section 4 looks straightforward, not too computational.